# TypeError: _vm(...).SyntheticModule is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, jestjs, esbuild

I am using [esbuild-jest](https://github.com/aelbore/esbuild-jest) package as jest code transformer.

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    '\\.[jt]sx?$': 'esbuild-jest',
  },
};
```

`index.ts`:

```
export default function myFunc(): string {
  return 'real value';
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
describe('test suites', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it('test one', async () => {
    jest.doMock('./index', () => jest.fn(() => 'one'));
    const myFunc = (await import('.')).default;
    expect(myFunc()).toBe('one');
  });
});
```

When I run the `jest` command, got an error:

```
FAIL  stackoverflow/71166203/index.test.ts
  test suites
    ✕ test one (5 ms)

  ● test suites › test one

    TypeError: _vm(...).SyntheticModule is not a constructor



      at Runtime.loadCjsAsEsm (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:657:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/71166203/index.test.ts:26:20)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.297 s
```

package versions:

```json
"esbuild": "^0.14.21",
"esbuild-jest": "^0.5.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"typescript": "^4.1.2"
```

Node version: `v14.16.0`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hey @slideshowp2, I am getting the same error, did you mange to figure it out? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This error is not very nice. After some research, I realized it has something to do with the use of dynamic imports.

Following the docs I see you need some additional steps to be able to use `(await import('.')).default;` inside your tests:

> Using jest.doMock() with ES6 imports requires additional steps. Follow these if you don't want to use require in your tests:
>
> - We have to specify the __esModule: true property (see the jest.mock() API for more information).
> - Static ES6 module imports are hoisted to the top of the file, so instead we have to import them dynamically using import().
> - Finally, we need an environment which supports dynamic importing. Please see Using Babel for the initial setup. Then add the plugin babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node, or an equivalent, to your Babel config to enable dynamic importing in Node.

reference: https://jestjs.io/docs/next/jest-object